# ChannelOutboundBuffer allocating more than 2GB and OOMing my executors

Tags: scala, apache-spark, netty

I'm running spark on a hadoop cluster. During a (huge) shuffle phase, some executors are crashing due to Out Of Memory.

While investigating, I see that the OOM is triggered in a netty thread, due to a `ChannelOutboundBuffer` trying to grow to really huge values (I think it's 2GB and trying to double it).
I have looked at some source code for Spark and Netty and have the following questions:

- is it allowed for a `ChannelOutboundBuffer` to grow that big? (ie over 2GB)
- during a shuffle, what is supposed to be the size of the outbound buffers that are generated for netty ? According to [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4a4dd4f36f65410ef5c87f7b61a960373f044e61/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/shuffle/IndexShuffleBlockResolver.scala#L193) it seems that one buffer will contain **all** the data is needed by the executor requesting the shuffle (so no split even if this is a lot of data). Is this correct?
- Even if all the data is put into a single netty buffer, I'm assuming that netty doesn't require to have a full copy of the data in it `ChannelOutboundBuffer` before sending it, as it could stream it. In that case why would it try to cache so much of the data in the `ChannelOutboundBuffer` before sending it?